# How can I run old linux packages on new distro without VM or Virtualbox?

Tags: package-management, wine, docker, flatpak

I want to run an old version of MythTV written for Ubuntu 12.04, on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.  I don't want to run the latest MythTV, I want **my** MTV!  Obviously I can (and am currently) run it in a virtual environment running Ubuntu 12.04, but this is not a satisfying solution.

Is there a Wine-equivalent for older linux kernel?  Or is this a job for docker/flatpak?  Assuming I could package it, would a flatpak/docker of a program built with linux 3.xx run on a linux 5.xx platform?

Comment: I doubt it, Ubuntu has gone though a lot of changes underneath the hood since 12.04, and seems to be limited need to have old programs work on newer kernels.  It is a shame when new improved programs suck.  Hopefully the people on here who know what they are talking about can help.

Comment: Snaps too are an answer; you can build on one system (where it works well), but the *snap* once built will run on any other system/release that has *snaps* enabled for execution. Building snaps on systems older than 16.04 has been done, but as the tools didn't reach maturity till ~16.04 more work/skill is required (at least that's my understanding from blogs).

Comment: @guiverc  He wants to build old program on newer Ubuntu, can that be done?  Like running a XP era program on Win 10.

Comment: @crip659 I would do it by starting a VM (lxc maybe; as *precise* [12.04] templates exist) and building the *snap* there, thus the *host* release doesn't matter (I can use my *hirsute* system, the OP their *focal*).  I've not done it though; it's what I'd likely do if I was trying to achieve what the OP wants.  The VM being used only the create the *snap*; the packaged snap is then run in the *focal* system directly (or any other release in the future).